# XCode version can use it on OSX 10.5.8?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have OSX 10.5.8 on mac Power Mac G5 , and I'm taking a C programming class right now

I download  the version xcode 5.1 but its not working in my machine what's the xcode i can instal in my mac ?

Comment: For lastest xcode you need OSX > 10.7. I am not sure if Power mac based systems supports these latest Mac OSX versions. You may need a intel based mac for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review this [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) here you can find all the details about `Xcode` versions with `Mac OS X` required means Versions compare table as per your OSX 10.5.8  and you can go to the [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) for download the `xcode`

`Xcode Version`     `Release Date`   and `Mac OS X` requied and `iOS Version`

[image]

Comment: Xcode 3.2 was released with Mac OS X v10.6 "Snow Leopard" and installs on no earlier version of OS X. It supports static program analysis, among other features. It also drops official support for targeting versions earlier than iPhone OS 3.0. But it is still possible to target older versions, and the simulator supports iPhone OS 2.0 through 3.1. Also, Java support is "exiled" in 3.2 to the organizer.